# Drawing circle in canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics

I recently started learning programming in c#. First of all I drew a simple circle, but I have problem with "char" -e.Graphics. I have necessary namespaces like System.Drawing and System.windows.Form
Program is concern with WPF Application. I would like to be able to enter the sizes and press a button to draw the circle.

```
 namespace drawcircle
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logika interakcji dla klasy MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window             
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();   
        }

        private void circle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int iks = int.Parse(beginx.Text);
            int igrek = int.Parse(beginy.Text);
            int width = int.Parse(wid.Text);
            int height = int.Parse(hei.Text);

           draw.circle(iks, igrek, width, height);
        }


    class draw
    {
        public static void circle(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            Pen color = new Pen(Color.Red);
            System.Drawing.SolidBrush fillblack = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Black);

            Rectangle circle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
                g.DrawEllipse(color, circle);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `e` isn't in scope in `draw.circle`... You'll need to pass it in as a parameter to that method.

Comment: but if I add PaintEventArgs e as parameter, what Am I supposed to write to draw.circle(iks, igrek, width, height), whats variable?

Comment: `public static void circle(int x, int y, int width, int height, RoutedEventArgs e)` would be the new signature, and call it like `draw.circle(iks, igrek, width, height, e);`

Comment: I think you may need to spend more time studying C# to learn about parameters.

Answer (score 8):

First off, you've made a method for `winforms` (if you need to import `.Forms` in `wpf` you should know that its wrong). Things like `SolidBrush` and `Color.Red` don't exist `wpf`. In winforms the solution would be a very small change:

## Winforms

**How to call:**

```
draw.circle(10, 20, 40, 40, this.CreateGraphics());
```

**Class:**

```
class draw
{
    public static void circle(int x, int y, int width, int height, Graphics g)
    {
        Pen color = new Pen(Color.Red);
        System.Drawing.SolidBrush fillblack = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Rectangle circle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        g.DrawEllipse(color, circle);
    }
}
```

---

For wpf I would try to do something like this:

## WPF

**How to call:**

```
draw.circle(10, 10, 100, 100, MainCanvas);
```

**Class:**

```
class draw
{
    public static void circle(int x, int y, int width, int height, Canvas cv)
    {

        Ellipse circle = new Ellipse()
        {
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            Stroke = Brushes.Red,
            StrokeThickness = 6
        };

        cv.Children.Add(circle);

        circle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)x);
        circle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (double)y);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**
Change your grid to a canvas and name it like so:

```
<Canvas Name="MainCanvas">

</Canvas>
```